# kibana how to give Role or Access to user to see Only One Single Dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-4, kibana-5

[image]

These are the Dashboards I created using Vizualisations. Lets say When User SignIn to KIbana, It should display only one Dashboard based on role.

Eg: I want to show App Analytics Dashboard to one person and Order Payment Analytics Dashboard to another Person with different Role. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have [X-Pack Security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/built-in-roles.html) in order to leverage the `kibana_dashboard_only_user` role + another role that gives access to only a selected list of dashboards for that user.

Comment: Yes, I tried with kibana_dashboard_only_user but It is showing all the dashboards by removing the links in the sidebar. In my case it  should hide the links links in sidebar for which I can use Build in roles.
How I should hide other dashboards.

Comment: Are those dashboards using the same index or a different one?

Comment: MIxed with multiple Visualizations and Visualizations with different indexes

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need X-pack, On top of that you can allow access to certain dashboards by 
create a role
Associate the index that the dashboards uses
Assign the role to the users along with the Dashboard_only_user role.

But you cant hide the other dashboards name from being displayed in the dashboard menu, its just gonna be empty if they dont have access to that dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps.

1. create a space in "Spaces" under stack management.
2. export the Saved Objects of the dashbaord with its related objects from the existing space (default)
3. import that saved object to your new space.
4. Create a viewer role with the new space you created.
5. assign that to your user.
6. done!